# Form desalinhando em resolução alta

Tags: delphi

Meu *form* está desalinhando quando o aplicativo roda em monitor com a resolução maior que a minha, o `borderstyle` está em `bsnone` e mesmo assim continua desalinhando, eu também setei todas as propriedade `anchors` pra `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,MrHelp.
Eu tenho o problema com resoluções abaixo de 1024, então tive que recorrer a uma re-dimensionamento da tela manualmente.

A tela principal deixo o BorderStyple:=bsSizeable;

```
Const nTamOriginal = 1280 // resolução da minha tela
var nEsc : Double;
    nInst: ianteger;
if nTamOriginal <> Screen.width then
begin
    nEsc := ( Screen.Width -nTamOriginal ) / nTamOriginal;
    nInt := Round( ( nEsc*100 ) + 100 );
    Self.Width := Round( Self.Width * ( nEsc +1 ) );
    Self.Height:= Round( Self.Height* ( nEsc +1 ) );
    Self.ScaleBy( nInt, 100 );
end;
Self.Top := 0;
Self.Left := 0;
```

Teste na sua aplicação, a propósito coloque no Create do formulário.